# How do I get rid of the extra white space between containers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Here is the link. http://www.cousinslawncare.com/ I would like to make the space between the serves smaller.

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? please check [This SO tour guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to ask

Comment: Create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

All columns have 15px padding on the left and right (comes from Bootstrap CSS). To overwrite those add the specific classname (in this case `.col-md-4`) to your custom stylesheet and set padding according to your preference. It would look like this:

```
 .col-md-4 {
 padding-left: 5px; // or whatever value you need
 padding-right: 5px; // or whatever value you need
 }
```

Make sure your custom stylesheet is loaded after Bootstrap CSS is loaded.